# Pick up a sample of image with eyedropper tool in CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, eyedropper

I am new to Photoshop technology and today i want to ask you a question. How do i pick up a sample/ a portion of an image with the Eyedropper tool, instead of picking up a simple color, and then draw with that sample all over the image in Adobe Photoshop CS5?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know PS but if it works like Gimp, you do a clipboard copy of the area of interest and you can then choose the "clipboard" brush or pattern.

Comment: You can't do that with the eyedropper.  You could make a selection with one of the selection tools, and then hit Copy (CTRL+C) then Paste (CTRL+V). Or you could define the selection as a Brush, or you could use the Clone Stamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Photoshop's Eyedropper tool does not work in that manner and has no such functionality. The Eyedropper picks up color and places color markers, that's all it does.

If you are interested in duplicating entire pieces of an image, you may want to look at the **Stamp Tools** ([Check here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/retouching-repairing-images.html))

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that what they really want is the clone stamp tool

Comment: @Cai HA! I was editing when you posted that :) Good catch

Answer (score 0):

Eyedropper tool is used to sample a single color. What you want can achieved with a Stamp Tool or Healing Brush tool, they should be just below the eyedropper. Once you select one of these, select the brush size, go to area you want to sample and Alt+click on it. Now you can simply paint anywhere on the document using the same tool.